# Can't seem to exclude a field in a django form

Tags: django, django-views, django-models

I have a Django project in which I have a view subclassed from the Django `CreateView` class. This view is used to upload a file to the server, and uses an `UploadedFile` model which I have created. The `UploadedFile` also needs to be associated with a project, which is stored as a `ForeignKey` called `project` in the `UploadedFile` model.

The project id is passed in as part of the URL: `(r'^projects/(?P<proj_key>\d+)/$', UploadedFileCreateView.as_view(), {}, 'upload-new')`

Because `project` is not really a form field, I know I need to exclude it using a `ModelForm`; however, even after I have done so, django never enters the `form_valid` method (if I put a logging call in it, it will never be written to the log, though logging works fine). I'm guessing that the `ForeignKey` is the culprit because as far as I can tell it worked before I added that in. I don't understand why django doesn't consider the form to be valid even after I excluded `project`.

Here is my `model` definition:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    """This is a project that is owned by a user and contains many UploadedFiles."""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class UploadedFile(models.Model):
    """This represents a file that has been uploaded to the server."""
    STATE_UPLOADED = 0
    STATE_ANNOTATED = 1
    STATE_PROCESSING = 2
    STATE_PROCESSED = 4
    STATES = (
        (STATE_UPLOADED, "Uploaded"),
        (STATE_ANNOTATED, "Annotated"),
        (STATE_PROCESSING, "Processing"),
        (STATE_PROCESSED, "Processed"),
    )

    status = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=STATES,
        default=0, blank=True, null=True) 
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=settings.XML_ROOT)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.file.name

    def name(self):
        return os.path.basename(self.file.name)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.status:
            self.status = self.STATE_UPLOADED
        super(UploadedFile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        os.remove(self.file.path)
        self.file.delete(False)
        super(UploadedFile, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)

class UploadedFileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UploadedFile
        excludes = ('project',)
```

Here is my view definition:

```
class UploadedFileCreateView(CreateView):
    model = UploadedFile

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.project_id = self.kwargs['proj_key']
        self.object.save()
        f = self.request.FILES.get('file')
        data = [{'name': f.name,
            'url': settings.MEDIA_URL + "files/" + f.name.replace(" ", "_"),
            'project': self.object.project.get().pk,
            'delete_url': reverse('fileupload:upload-delete',
                args=[self.object.id]),
            'delete_type': "DELETE"}]
        response = JSONResponse(data, {}, response_mimetype(self.request))
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=files.json'
        return super(UploadedFileCreateView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(UploadedFileCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two likely problems:

1) The form keyword is `exclude`, not `excludes`.

Generally the recommendation is to favor explicitly listing `fields` to be included, so you don't accidentally expose any fields you might later add, but `exclude` will work.

2) You're not actually using your custom form class in the view. Set the `form_class` attribute to `UploadedFileForm`.

Comment: Your solution worked! Unfortunately, it only uncovered another problem; but thank you anyway.